# MySQL: update on a table with multiple foreign key dependencies

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Below is the simplified picture of the relationships I have in my DB:

```
create table attribute (id int auto_increment, primary key (id));
create table state_sample (id int auto_increment, primary key(id));
create table state_sample_attribute (
    state_sample_id int,
    attribute_id int,
    primary key(state_sample_id, attribute_id),
    foreign key (state_sample_id) references state_sample(id) on update cascade,
    foreign key (attribute_id) references attribute(id) on update cascade
);
create table note (
    id int auto_increment,
    state_sample_id int,
    attribute_id int,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key (state_sample_id) references state_sample(id) on update cascade,
    foreign key (state_sample_id, attribute_id)
        references state_sample_attribute(state_sample_id, attribute_id) on update cascade
);

insert into attribute values (1);
insert into state_sample values (1);
insert into state_sample_attribute values (1, 1);
insert into note values (1, 1, 1);
```

Whenever I try to update the ss table, it fails:

```
update state_sample set id = 2;
```

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`demotemplate`.`note`, CONSTRAINT `note_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_id`) REFERENCES `ss` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

As far as I understand, this is what happens:

- It tries to set state_sample.id = 2.
- It sees the cascade to note and tries to update note.state_sample_id.
- However, note.state_sample_id is also involved in the foreign key to to state_sample_attribute(state_sample_id, attribute_id), so it goes to check whether that's still valid.
- As state_sample_attribute.state_sample_id has not yet been updated, the constraint fails.

Is my assumption correct? And if so, is there a way to work this around?

Comment: These table relationships smell like a poor design. Can you explain the use case that requires it? Maybe we can help you fix the relationships. It probably just needs to be normalized better, but it's hard to picture it with meaningless column names.

Comment: The 4th & 1st FKs imply the 3rd. So you don't need the 3rd. (In fact we almost always rely on transitivity to reduce what FK constraints we declare, updates aside.) Unfortunately also in MySQL we are limited in how we can express cascades even though the DBMS could figure out what simpler cases are the same as more complex cases. See the manual re FK updates. PS Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: I've updated the DDL with meaningful names, so the idea is clear. state_sample_attribute has a composite primary key of (state_sample_id, attribute_id), and that's what I reference from note.

Comment: The names don't matter to my comment. Please excuse me, you did give a MCVE, I missed the update in your first version. Do read the manual sections on FKs because there is a clear discussion re multiple cascades to the same table. PS Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn to use `@` to notify one non-poster non-sole commenter of a comment it is in. I learned of this comment saying you edited only now coming by because you answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved it in the end is dropping the extra FK:

```
alter table note drop foreign key (state_sample_id) references state_sample(id);
```

Comment: Like I said in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Give the `ssa` table its own `id` primary key, and use that in the foreign key in `notes`, rather than referencing the `ss_id` and `a_id` columns.

```
create table ssa (
    id int auto_increment,
    ss_id int, 
    a_id int, 
    primary key (id),
    unique key (ss_id, a_id), 
    foreign key (ss_id) references ss(id) on update cascade, 
    foreign key (a_id) references a(id) on update cascade);
create table note (
    id int auto_increment, 
    ss_id int, 
    ssa_id int, 
    primary key(id), 
    foreign key (ss_id) references ss(id) on update cascade, 
    foreign key (ssa_id) references ssa(id) on update cascade);
```

Now you don't have the redundant dependency.

It's also not clear that `note` needs `ss_id` at all, since it's redundant with the related `ssa` row.

Answer (score 1):

Try

> DISABLE KEYS

or

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

make sure to turn it on

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

after.

Comment: Will that still do the cascades?